# Django Field 'id' expected a number but got 'autobiography'

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I am working on a project that allows me to upload books to database and sort them by them their collection. The problem is that whenever i upload and try to filter out books from a particular collection i get the error ***Field 'id' expected a number but got 'autobiography'***

models.py

```
class BookDetails(models.Model):
    collections = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=COLLECTION, default="")
   

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "BookDetails"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.collections

class Books(models.Model):
    """
    This is for models.py
    """
    book_title = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="", primary_key=True)
    book = models.FileField(default="", upload_to="books", validators=[validate_book_extension], verbose_name="books")
    collection = models.ForeignKey(BookDetails, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Books"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.book_title
```

forms.py

```
class BookInfo(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = BookDetails
        fields = ["collections",]

class BookFile(BookInfo):
    book = forms.FileField(widget = forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={"multiple":True}))
    class Meta(BookInfo.Meta):
        fields = BookInfo.Meta.fields + ["book",]
```

views.py

```
def books(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = BookFile(request.POST, request.FILES)
        files = request.FILES.getlist("book")
        try:
            if form.is_valid():
                collection = form.save(commit=False)
                collection.save()
                if files:
                    for f in files:
                        names = str(f)
                        name = names.strip(".pdf")
                        Books.objects.create(collection=collection, book_title=name, book=f)
                return redirect(index)
        except IntegrityError:
            messages.error(request, "value exist in database")
            return redirect(books)
    else:
        form = BookFile()
    return render(request, "books.html", {"form":form})


def test(request):
    data = Books.objects.filter(collection="autobiography")
    template = loader.get_template('test.html')
    context = {"data":data}
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

so basically what i am trying to achieve is to be able to filter the books based on their collections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you pass `collections` field value in filter value. So it give errors. You can use below queryset.

```
data = Books.objects.filter(collection__collections="autobiography")
```